# NetNamedPipe: varying response time when communication is idling

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, named-pipes, performance

I have two WCF apps communicating one-way over named pipes. All is nice, except for one thing:
Normally, the request/response cycle takes zero (marginal) time. However, if there was a time span of, say, half a minute without any communication, the request/response increases up to ~300-500ms.

I looked around the net and I got the idea of using a heart beat/ping mechanism to keep the  communication channel busy. Using trial and error I found that when doing a request each 10 seconds, the response times stay low. Starting at around 15s intervals, the "hiccup" response times begin to appear.

Now I'm wondering where this phenomenon is originating from. I tried setting alle conceivable timeouts on both sides to > 1 minute, but that did not help.

Can anybody explain what's going on there?

Comment: I am having this same problem.  At first I suspected caching, but new data is returned instantly, if it is requested within 15 seconds of a previous call to the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Wenlong Dong's blog post, [Why Does WCF Become Slow After Being Idle For 15 Seconds?](http://blogs.msdn.com/wenlong/archive/2010/02/11/why-does-wcf-become-slow-after-being-idle-for-15-seconds.aspx)

The post also includes a workaround until it gets fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the idling process is being paged to disk? If you keep the *processes* at both ends busy, but don't make the *connection* busy, does it still happen?

That may well not be it, but it's possibly worth a try.

Comment: I tried it and added to both processes a thread doing some silly calculations. CPU usage remained at 0% for both of them, but I think it was still enough to keep them from being paged out. Alas, the described probelm remains unaffected.
It was definitely worth a try, though. Thanks for the suggestion-