# WCF: reducing first call delay. Best practice

Tags: .net, wcf

I have WCF client that connects to server in Intranet. The very first call takes significant time and user waits patiently until it completes. Second, third calls are at least 30% faster.

What is the best practice to keep WCF client ready to call? I'm thinking about background thread that pings server from time to time (or may be the very first time application starts) but may be there are better/simpler ways?

Service is IIS6 hosted with wsHttp(Dual)Bindings. Problem is serious with Dual endpoint.

Comment: Hi Andrew, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765938/netnamedpipe-varying-response-time-when-communication-is-idling/2821160#2821160

Comment: Is this service hosted in IIS?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: yes, but application pool is never idle.

Comment: can you give a specific amount of time difference instead of '30%'?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior could be related to the fact that the application pool in IIS is not loaded into memory when the first request arrives.

Comment: It's hardly so, because I administered IIS not to shutdown pool and observe the delay on every client in organization (there are about ten installations).

Comment: How about the very first request after the server reboot?

Comment: Thank you for the attention I'll investigate it a bit later